# Screen blank after upgrading to 22.04, no bios information

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, lubuntu

I have recently upgrade from Lubuntu 20.04. to 22.04. The problem is that now when I start the PC, I get blank screen. The system was working well, and then I had a kernel update. I would do the reinstall, but the biggest problem is when I power on my laptop, it doesn't even show the bios or anything,, just black screen turns on (I can see it is turned on, there is light). So, I would like to ask for assistance, as I use this PC for work and it is very urgent. Also, once I just tried restarting, and eventually it showed the screen where I enter the encryption password. Now it doesn't help as much as I restart it.

Thankful in advance,
Joao

Comment: I would likely boot a *live* system on thumb-drive, to ensure your PC/device is still functioning... ie. your issue isn't hardware.  I'd likely try firstly something rather different (*esp. if you have it available; I'd have Debian on thumb-drives, likely Knoppix etc not counting Ubuntu systems*) then something like what you normally use.  Does it work on those?  If so I'd boot a 22.04 system using the same kernel (*you didn't specify, if your 20.04 used GA, you'll be using GA on 22.04, if using HWE on 20.04 you'll use HWE on 22.04*).. If thats good, I'd copy your data off & consider next move

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I boot thumb-drive, as it doesn't show any screen, nor offers any bios options?

Comment: I'd hope I'd know how to use my own devices... however if you're not seeing any normal POST (*power on self test*) or machine branding on the device on screen (ie. what you'd see normally)... I'd likely suspect your issue is your device hardware...  If you're seeing nothing; I'd concentrate on booting your uEFI/Firmware configs/diagnostics first; as if that can't be used; you're unlikely to be able to use any additional software (such as OS on drive, internal or external)..   This really though is device specific...

Comment: I see, my laptop model is Lenovo V110-15AST. I tried booting to novo button, but it didn't work. Also no signs or anything, just blank screen with backlight. It happened once already, but after turning the laptop on and off after 3 times it booted into Lenovo sign and everything worked normally. I have also replaced the BIOS battery, forgot to mention that.

Comment: My view from what you describe, is you have a hardware issue.. This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, where you're be better suited (*as I read what you've put*) seeking help on a hardware site. I don't know if Stack Exchange has anything suitable sorry, but as I read it; your issue is not Ubuntu or in fact related to the OS or software, but hardware issues.

Comment: Also, in addition, when I type my encryption password "blindly", it simulates computer starting, as the screen goes off a bit. Hard disk is normally started. I somehow think it might be a faulty graphics driver. Is there away to fix it in this situation?

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot

Comment: Boot it multi times and then it works? Hardware.

Comment: If it's related to kernel modules (ie. graphics *driver* as you put it), then the kernel stack comment detail in my first comment (ie. your chosen kernel stack of 22.04 is based on what you had when you were on 20.04; if you'd not changed it post-install; your installation media would have set the kernel stack being used)... but I'd still explore using *live* media.  Lubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 media will use the GA kernel stack (5.15) & can be used to test GA, 22.04.2 media will use HWE (5.19) & can test that on your hardware...  ie. I'd explore using *live* media as stated initially